# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null

Tags: javascript

> carousel.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null**

**I got this error when I'm going to ad slider to the page.**

here is the js code for the error.

```
const track = document.querySelector('.carousel_track');    
const slides = Array.from(track.children);    
const dotsNav = document.querySelector('.carousel_nav');    
const dots = Array.from(dotsNav.children);   //here 
const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;    
slides[0].style.left = 0;    
slides[1].style.left = slideWidth + 'px';
```

Can anyone give me a solution for this? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: you need to post your html as well

Comment: where at dotsnav or track?

Comment: The obvious answer is that `dotsNav` is null because either your selector is wrong, or the element you think exists does not exist. Without the HTML it's impossible to really tell.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error throws here `const dots = Array.from(dotsNav.children); //here` , though the source of error is coming from previous line.
The error hints that the track is null, which can happen when the selector didn't return any value.

Without seeing your HTML code its not so clear whats the exact reason, but its obvious that the element with class `carousel_nav` doesn't exist in the DOM at the moment of execution of this code.

Steps to debug:

1. Do the console log after acquiring the track object.

```js
const dots = document.querySelector('.carousel_nav');

console.log('Dots are: ', dots);
...
```

Then on the console of the browser check the value, its probably null.

2. Check if the class is written correctly on the HTML element, without typos and mistakes. You can even run the js directly on the browsers console to see if the code is actually fetching `.carousel_nav`
3. If when you run your js code in browser's console and it returns actual value instead of null, but on the page load it still returns null then it can mean the carousel is being initialized by 3rd party library after certain event, most probably `document.ready`, you have to as well listen to the `document ready` event and only after that execute your code.
   Sometimes just waiting for the `document ready` is not enough, so check the documentation of the library that you use, it should have some callback where you can execute your code exactly after the carousel is being initialized.
4. Might be that the carouself library that you use, need an additional parameter to render dots, do you actually see the dots in the rendered dom?

If you need more hints, provide the library name youre using and also html

P.S.
Sorry I didn't see `//here` comment. But the debugging steps are the same